# ASP.NET Core 2 with Entity Framework, showing no connection string named '####' could be found in the application config file

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I am writing an ASP.NET Core MVC application. I am using Entity Framework. I have a data access layer where I have added my edmx from the database I designed. The MVC project is referencing this data access project.

When I try to access something from DB, this error occurs:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>
> InvalidOperationException: No connection string named 'DefaultConnection' could be found in the application config file.
>
> System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.get_ConnectionHasModel()

I have set up my connection string in both data access project and Core project.
But still getting this error.

This is the `appsetting.json`:

```
{
  "Data": {
    "DefaultConnection": {
      "ConnectionString": "**My DB Details**"
    }
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: You tagged entity-framework-6. Are you actually using EF 6, or are you using EF Core?

Comment: Entity Framework is in DataAccess project which is a .NET framework class library. Yes it is using EF 6.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I had to compromise because of lack of time. I am now using EF core in the ASP.NET Core project and it's working fine. Removed the DataAccess Layer. Will use it once all the bugs with .NET Core are resolved.

Comment: Well, newer version don't have these issues. I am using .NET Core 3.1 with EF Core.

Answer (score 3):

It's not that straight forward when you have a `.NET Core` web project and it's backed by a `EF6` project as class library.

In order to get things working, you might have to:

- Reference full framework in `.NET Core` web project
- Provide the connection string using `Factory` pattern to the `DbContext`
- Share the connection string in both projects, maybe via environment variables

Manually creating a `web.config` in the `.NET Core` web project is bad as it doesn't have one until you publish. The `web.config` would be created by then based on the `appsetting`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/entity-framework-6?view=aspnetcore-2.1 is the documentation on how to get the `.NET Core` and `EF6` talking.

Comment: I tried that and now I am getting Unable to determine the provider name for provider factory of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientFactory'. Make sure that the ADO.NET provider is installed or registered in the application config. I am gonna try using EF core in a separate solution and see how to handle this.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using EF 6 in a .NET Framework library, then it's probably looking in the web.config. So put it in the web.config [as described here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/connection-strings#net-framework-applications):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection"
         connectionString="**My DB Details**" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

*Previous answer (for purely EF Core):*

[Connection strings in .NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/connection-strings#aspnet-core) should look like this:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "**My DB Details**"
}
```

Not the `"Data"` node that you have now.

Comment: This is the setting I had initially. Even this is not working.

Comment: I updated my answer. If it's in a .NET Framework library, then it's probably looking in the web.config for it.

Comment: The .net class library also has a connection string added as I've mentioned in the question.

Comment: It needs to be added to the web.config for the main MVC project. That's where it's looking.

Comment: In asp.net core mvc, there is no web.config. It's replaced with appsetting.json

Comment: That's not entirely true. If you're hosting in IIS on Windows, it's still used. Are you hosting in IIS?

Comment: This an under development website. Using visual studio and visual studio is using IIS-Express.

Comment: Ok. Then create a web.config file in the same folder as appsettings.json and put the connection string there.

Answer (score -2):

The appjson.config is wrong do this

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
      "DefaultConnection": "your connection string"
    }
```

Remove the Data tag and it should work.